# Solution of a trigonometric equation of two variables. Need to find the difference of them.

Tags: trigonometry

In today's class I came across this equation:
$\sin \phi - \sin \theta = k$ where $\phi,\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ are the two variables, while $k \in \mathbb{R}$ is a generic constant. We needed to find out the $\phi-\theta $ that solves the equation.

For our purpose, we assumed that both $\phi,\theta \ll 1 $, and therefore, we used Taylor. No problem at all!

But then, I asked myself: "What if we couldn't make that assumption?". 
Considering that I still want to find $\phi-\theta $, I tried to get something more similar to what I need.

I arrived, with a simple substitution, to 
\begin{equation}
2\sin(\phi/2-\theta/2)\cos(\phi/2+\theta/2)=k
\end{equation}

However, I still don't have a clue about how to get the solution. I know, I haven't done much, but I could go only this far. To me, it even seems a quite standard equation, and yet, I haven't found anything useful on the internet. Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm going to make a further "simplification".  Re-write your equation as:  $sin(x - y)cos(x + y) = K/2 = \bar{K}$.  Then, this is the level curve of the function on the left corresponding to the level $\bar{K}$.  This curve is perpendicular to the gradient of the function $z = sin(x - y)cos(x + y)$.  I haven't spent any more time than that, but the gradient is easy enough to compute $cos(2x)\hat{i} + -cos(2y) \hat{j}$, so it's perpendicular to that ($cos(2y)\hat{i} + -cos(2x)\hat{j}$)

Comment: Although, looking at the original equation, the gradient method would be simpler to use at that point.  Your original equation becomes $z = sin(x) - sin(y)$ and you're looking at the level curve $z = k$.  (Sorry, I use x and y because of a habit of notation, but $\theta$ and $\phi$ work, too)

Comment: $\theta$ and $\phi$ are related by $\phi =\sin^{-1}(k + \sin \theta)$. This is not a linear function. There is not a fixed difference between $\theta$ and $\phi$. When $\theta$ and $\phi$ are both small, then their difference will be approximately constant, so the solution method worked to give an approximate answer. But this does not hold in general.